# jquery datatable input text change to calculate other column

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is there a built in function or easy way to calculate the value for other column when input field in the datatable row gets changed ?

I am trying to calculate the total cost based on unit cost that user provides in the input field.

I have table with the below html code.

```
 <tr> 
<td> 150 <td/>
<td> <input type="number" ></td>
<td> total cost which i want to dynamically render based on above input value</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: could provide a JS Fiddle example of your page?  This isn't hard to do in DataTables but it will rely a bit on how you are initializing your grid, JSON structure, ..etc.  Would be helpful to have the rest of the code to get context.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of such problems reactive programming could be good for you. There is a library out there for Javascript: bacon.js. I don't know if it's well-suited for tables.